# how create a sql database fom a stongly typed dataset

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, xsd, ddl, strongly-typed-dataset

I'm looking for an easy way to transfer a database schema I have developed inside visual studio as a strongly typed dataset (xsd file) into a corresponding sql server database. Silly me I assumed the process would be forthright, but I can't find out how to do it. I assume I could duplicate the tables column by column, but that seems so error prone. Does anyone know of a way to perform the schema transfer like this? Maybe a tool to translate the xsd file into a corresponding sql server ddl file?

Final thought once I have the schema transferred moving data around between the two data stores will be straight forward, its just getting the schemas synced that has me stumped...

Thanks,
Keith

Comment: One big problem is XML supports data structures that don't translate well to relational tables. An XML object and a normalized schema are very different things.

Comment: Very true, luckily our saving grace is that our XML files are the embodiment of a strongly typed Dot.Net dataset which does map well to a relational database model. In fact we use the dataset as an in memory database. In the end our data model is in third normal form, which simplifies our issue to one of simply translating the model's representation from one form to another...

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't you implement your data model directly in SQL Server ?! It is more common and engineered and I think this is why Microsoft has not provided any wizard or tool for this case. As well you can make your data model as scripts or .sql files and they can be managed via SVN and whenever you need the model implementation you can sue them.

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback. The (existing)application in question is required to keep it's data in an open format like xml, so that individual datasets could be easily passed around among a large number of disconnected and isolated systems. Now it is time to allow these systems to confederate into groups. When that is done 1000s of these datasets will need to be merged and managed collectively, and hence the need for a "real" DB engine like SQL.

Comment: So each instance of this application has an XML beside, right ?!

Comment: Actually they have hundreds. Basically our users are creating digital archives of their library's special collections. One book -> one digital rendering (raw + processed images), where all of the collected / generated metadata about the book ends up in a dataset for the book. The dataset plus all of the scanned images equals the book, The libraries can then share these resultant digital objects amongst themselves as they see fit. All told each book is about 5-10 GB in size. Because these objects are for archival purposes the results must be standalone by nature.